# parsing strings in string.ini using PHP

Tags: php, string, string-matching

I have a `strings.ini` file where I am defining all the strings like

```
tz1 = "UTC+4:30 Asia/Kabul"
tz2 = "UTC+5:45 Asia/Katmandu"
tz3 = "UTC-4:30 America/Caracas"
```

I have a substring value `5:45`. Based on that I want to get LHS part `tz2`. How to do this using PHP?

Comment: `^\w+(?=\s*=\s*"[^"]*\b5:45\b)`

Comment: Is that an ini file?

Comment: @SunShine You already have a function called `parse_ini_file()` in PHP, which helps you do this.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say, you have `settings.ini` file. You can use [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function to do this:

**`settings.ini`**

```
[base]
    tz1 = "UTC+4:30 Asia/Kabul"
    tz2 = "UTC+5:45 Asia/Katmandu"
    tz3 = "UTC-4:30 America/Caracas"
```

**PHP File**

```
// Parse without sections
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("settings.ini");
print_r($ini_array);
```

This would output:

```
Array
(
    [tz1] => "UTC+4:30 Asia/Kabul"
    [tz2] => "UTC+5:45 Asia/Katmandu"
    [tz3] => "UTC-4:30 America/Caracas"
)
```

Now you can get the value of `tz2` and get the value as:

```
$ini = explode(" ", $ini_array["tz2"]);
$ini = str_replace("UTC", "", $ini);
```

So, your `$ini` value will be: `+5:45`.

You can also loop through it to get both the LHS and RHS. `:)`

Comment: Is there any limit for that ? I have some 5300 lines of strings in the ini file and I am not getting all the strings in the array.

Comment: @SunShine I believe so. What's the length of your `ini` file?

Comment: @SunShine Length or Depth?

Comment: more than 25000 words, 5000 lines

Comment: @SunShine Can I give you a better approach for this? Can you try JSON or YAML? Coz I believe this would be too much for an `ini` file.

Comment: No, I cannot change it now, isn't there any other option ?

Comment: You can change another option. That's what I was about to say... Where did you go?

Comment: There's an option called `max_` something in `php.ini`. That should work out for you.